# Obtaining data from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the variable $fileData which contains the following array

```
array:2 [▼
  "folder1" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "something.png"
    1 => "something.png"
  ]
  "folder2" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "something.png"
    1 => "something.png"
  ]
]
```

What I am trying to do is add the folder names (folder1 and folder2) as select options.  I am doing some testing and for some reason I am finding it difficult to access the folder names.
If I do

```
foreach($fileData as $data) {
    var_dump($data);
}
```

It will output the actual content of folder1 and folder2 e.g.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "something.png"
  1 => "something.png"
]
```

So how would I go about getting the actual folder names without knowing what these names are?

Thanks

Comment: why you don' try foreach($fileData as $data => $value) { var_dump($value);}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the name(index) of each occurance the first array so use the foreach with both `as` parameters like this

```
foreach($fileData as $folder => $files) {
    echo "Folder name is $folder\n";
    foreach($files as $file) {
        echo "....Contains $file\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Believe it or not I did do this and it wasnt working, but now it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through the Array using `foreach` Looping Construct and then build your Select `<option>` accordingly like so:

```
<?php

$arrPix     =  [
      "folder1" =>[
        0 => "something.png",
        1 => "something.png",
      ],
      "folder2" => [
        0 => "something.png",
        1 => "something.png",
      ]
];
$select = "<select name='img_folders' id='img_folder' class='form-control img_folders'>" . PHP_EOL;

foreach($arrPix as $folderName=>$arrImg){
    $select .="<option name='{$folderName}'>{$folderName}</option>option";
}
$select .= "</select>" . PHP_EOL;

echo $select;
```